# Brocho on Chalitzo

Tags: halacha, blessing, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

Is there a Brocho that is said on Chalitzo? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Bracha" Translated  is said by the Beis Din it is:

"May it be G‑d's will that the daughters of Israel will never need to perform either Chalitzah or Yibum. Blessed are You, King of the universe, Who has sanctified us with the commandments and statutes of Abraham our father."

[SOURCE OF TRANSLATION](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/558049/jewish/Yibum-and-Chalitzah.htm)

Comment: That's interesting. Why Avraham?

Comment: Because by the war with the Five Kings he did not take anything Hashem rewarded him by giving us the mitzvah of teffilin tztzis and Chalitzah

Comment: @SimchasTorah please tag IsaacMoses if you want him to see your comment.

Comment: @simchastorah what is the source of that statement?

Comment: @SethJ It's in Shulchan Aruch Seder Chalitza 57 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9728&st=&pgnum=223&hilite=

Comment: @HachamGabriel http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/855/759

Comment: October 2010 was on the old platform, when notifications worked differently anyway.